# VB.NET print a DataSet data in Webforms page via For Each Loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, foreach, webforms

I am using following code in my code behind to Pass data to my aspx page.

```
Public Function GetFirstElement() As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim alUtil As New ALUtility
    Dim connString As String = AppSettings("conSQL")
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connString)
        cnn.Open()
        Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM case", cnn)
            dad.Fill(ds)
        End Using
        cnn.Close()
    End Using
    Return ds

End Function
```

And I am trying to loop through inside aspx page with the following code

```
 <% For Each dataRow As Data.DataRow In Me.GetFirstElement().Tables(0).Rows %> 

                                <div class="widget-body padset-lg">
                                    <div class="row cancel-paddings">
                                        <div class="col-md-1">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-11">
                                            <h2 class="darker-text font-size-sm fonts-tight cancel-margin fonts-bold margset-bottom-md">
                                               <%= dataRow["short_description"].ToString() %></h2>
                                            <p class="pale-text font-size-sm cancel-margin fonts-bold">
                                               <%= dataRow["case_id"].ToString() %></p>
                                            <p class="darker-text font-size-xs fonts-tight fonts-bold cancel-margin">
                                                Medium Priority, New<br />
                                                John Doe ABC Company,
                                                <br />
                                                10.23AM, 12/11/2016</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-content height-auto">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                    </div>
                    <% Next%>
```

When I try to run this loop I am getting the following error.

> BC30203: Identifier expected.

Can someone help me on this. I am a C# programmer and new to the VB.NET. I have successfully used loops with C# but same methods in VB is not working. And I tried asp:Repeater too. With that I am getting "container not defined" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we strip off all HTML markups excluding ASP.NET special ones, we get this loop structure:

```
<% For Each dataRow As Data.DataRow In Me.GetFirstElement().Tables(0).Rows %> 

   <%-- omitted --%>

   <%= dataRow["short_description"].ToString() %>

   <%-- omitted --%>

   <%= dataRow["case_id"].ToString() %>

   <%-- omitted --%>

<% Next %>
```

It's clearly visible that `dataRow` is [`System.Data.DataRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) array to represent single row, so you need to use parentheses `(...)` instead of square brackets `[...]` when mentioning column names in VB.NET context:

```
<% For Each dataRow As Data.DataRow In Me.GetFirstElement().Tables(0).Rows %> 

   <%-- omitted --%>

   <%= dataRow("short_description").ToString() %>

   <%-- omitted --%>

   <%= dataRow("case_id").ToString() %>

   <%-- omitted --%>

<% Next %>
```

Reference:

[BC30203: Identifier expected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/identifier-expected#to-correct-this-error)

Answer (score 1):

Tyr this(your code behind) **case** should be **[dbo].[case]**.

```
Public Function GetFirstElement() As DataSet
   Dim ds As New DataSet
   Dim alUtil As New ALUtility
   Dim connString As String = AppSettings("conSQL")
   Using cnn As New SqlConnection(connString)
       cnn.Open()
       Using dad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [dbo].[case]", cnn)
           dad.Fill(ds)
       End Using
       cnn.Close()
   End Using
   Return ds

End Function
```

Your aspx code **<%= dataRow["short_description"].ToString() %>** should be **<%= dataRow("short_description").ToString() %>**.

```
    <div class="widget-body padset-lg">
        <div class="row cancel-paddings">
            <div class="col-md-1">
            </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                <h2 class="darker-text font-size-sm fonts-tight cancel-margin fonts-bold margset-bottom-md">
                <%= dataRow("short_description").ToString() %></h2>
                <p class="pale-text font-size-sm cancel-margin fonts-bold">
                <%= dataRow("case_id").ToString() %></p>
                <p class="darker-text font-size-xs fonts-tight fonts-bold cancel-margin">
                Medium Priority, New<br />
                John Doe ABC Company,
                <br />
                10.23AM, 12/11/2016</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="card-content height-auto">
        </div>
    </div>
```